# Can madExcept Freeze my Delphi Application?

Tags: delphi, madexcept

I have a Delphi 5-based application using madExcept 3.0m. It appearantly freezes due to madExcept, a product whose quality I admire and thus don't usually blame for anything.

Here's the code:

```
  AddLogEntry('ME_Settings');
  try
    AddLogEntry('ME_Settings2');
    with MESettings do begin                     // madExcept-Einstellungen
      AddLogEntry('FrozenMsg');
      sOldFrozenMsg := FrozenMsg;
      AddLogEntry('Meldung vorbereiten');
      FrozenMsg := AnsiString(_('Das Öffnen der Datenbank dauert ungewöhnlich lang.'));
      AddLogEntry('Remote?');
      [...]
    end;
  finally
    [...]
  end;
```

It doesn't throw any exception, it just seems to freeze upon reading `FrozenMsg`:
[image]
<sub>(source: [quodata.de](http://quodata.de/fileadmin/temp/Daub/log.png))</sub>

It doesn't happen on any of my computers, but does at the customer computer. How can madExcept's MESettings cause such a behaviour. How should I debug this?

Comment: Did you ask on the ME forum? Matthias is usually very responsive.

Comment: When your program freezes, what is it doing? Pause it in the debugger and find out.

Comment: @David: Thanks for sending me there: http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=27497

Comment: @Rob: Unfortunately, I cannot remote-debug on the customer computer and cannot reproduce the problem locally yet.

Comment: What is that `_('thing')`?

Comment: @WarrenP: Indeed, someone came up with this function name. Is is a shorthand for gettext(), a widespread translation system based on .po and .mo files. Implementations exist for many languages.

Comment: I quite like the use of the shortest most meaningless pascal identifier, `_`

Comment: So you HAVE removed MadExcept and sent a build to the customer, and the customer does NOT freeze? :-)

Comment: @WarrenP: Thanks for your feedback. It would be quite cumbersome to remove madExcept from the project entirely, because we make heavy use of many of its features. On the other hand, I tried an exe file without the freeze check (disabled via Project settings - .mes file) - same behaviour. I currently think that not madExcept, but something on the customer computer is causing the freeze.

Comment: By heavy use you mean you repeatedly call MadExcept in hundreds of places in your code?  So mock it out.  Create unit aliases and mock units.  I am sure I could do that in minutes, if not ever faster via #ifdefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now deployed a regular update using a regular (and very same) madExcept 3.0m to the customer. It worked. They replaced the computer due to other problems, so I am quite confident that the problem was with the specific computer and nothing needs to be fixed in madExcept or our products.